# JaCoCo coverage not reflecting cross-module tests in Maven multi-module project with Quarkus

Tags: unit-testing, quarkus, jacoco-maven-plugin

**Description:**

I am encountering an issue with JaCoCo coverage in my Maven multi-module project, which consists of two microservices: Module 1 (named "api") and Module 2 (named "core"). Both modules are developed using Quarkus and contain source (src) and test (test) directories.

**Project Structure:**

```
parent pom.xml
|
|
-----api (Module 1)
| |
| -----src
| | |
| | -----main
| |  ||
| |  |-----java
| |  | 
| |  -----test
| | 
| | 
| |
| -----pom.xml
|
|
-----core (Module 2)
|
-----src
| |
| -----main
|  | |
|  | -----java
|  |
|  -----test
| 
| 
|
-----pom.xml
```

**Problem Overview:**

1. *Configuration:* As per the Quarkus Documentation, JaCoCo is
   configured to consider test classes not annotated with @QuarkusTest
   by executing the prepare-agent goal.
2. *Current Status:* I have successfully obtained coverage reports for
   Module 1 (api) using the jacoco-maven-plugin and for Module2 (core)
   using quarkus-jacoco.
3. *Issue:* However, the coverage report does not accurately reflect the
   tests conducted in Module 2 (core) that involve methods from Module
   1 (api). This discrepancy arises due to the concurrent usage of both
   jacoco-maven-plugin and quarkus-jacoco.

**Request for Assistance:**
I seek suggestions and guidance on how to rectify this issue and ensure that cross-module tests are accurately reflected in the coverage reports for both modules. Any insights, recommendations, or best practices in configuring JaCoCo within a multi-module Quarkus project would be greatly appreciated.

**Screenshots for Reference:**
In this example isEmpty() is covered in api module but not in core module because the test is in api module .

[isEmpty() in core module coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSePL.png)
[isEmpty() in api module coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sdF0.png)